# Terraform plan trying to replace existing storage account resource

Tags: azure, yaml, terraform, pipeline, infrastructure

When I try to update latest terraform version terraform plan trying to replace storage account resource how to prevent that?

Tried life_cycle block

Comment: did you try `lifecycle { ignore_changes = all }` ?

Comment: Please add the relevant terraform code to the question along with the output you see.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by updating latest version, I tried to use azurm version 2.0.